# Looping through a json file to display nested info in dart/flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a json file structured like this:

#### assets/data.json

```
data = {
  users: [
    {
      id: 'u1',
      name: 'John',
    },
    {
      id: 'u2',
      name: 'Fred',
    },
    {
      id: 'u3',
      name: 'Robert',
    }
  ],
  threads: [
    {
      id: 't1',
      title: 'What is your favorite dog breed ?',
      publishedAt: 19191919191,
      posts: ['p1', 'p2'],
      userId: ''
    }
    {
      id: 't2',
      title: 'What is your favorite cat breed ?',
      publishedAt: 17171717171,
      posts: ['p3'],
      userId: ''
    }
  ]
  posts: [
    {
      id: 'p1',
      publishedAt: 19191919191,
      userId: 'u1',
      text: 'Golden Retriever',
      threadId: 't1'
    }
    {
      id: 'p2',
      publishedAt: 11111111111,
      userId: 'u2',
      text: 'Spitz',
      threadId: 't1'
    }
    {
      id: 'p3',
      publishedAt: 16161616161,
      userId: 'u3',
      text: 'Persan',
      threadId: 't2'
    }
  ]
}
```

#### My problem

I want to display threads then loop posts (with the associated user name) for each threads.
I can have a lot of threads and a lot of posts. (I'm not dealing with pagination right now but it could be interesting to have your thought on this)

To achieve this, I used for loop and if conditional statement. I'm not really convinced. I saw ListView and ListView.builder (maybe I can nest several ListView.builder) or groupBy but I don't know if the use of it is better.

Please find my code, I would be pleased if you could challenge it in order to make it better and know better practice.

#### main.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Forum',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HompePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HompePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HompePageState createState() => _HompePageState();
}

class _HompePageState extends State<HompePage> {
  List _threads = [];
  List _posts = [];
  List _users = [];

  // Fetch content from the json file
  Future<void> readJson() async {
    final String response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/data.json');
    final data = await json.decode(response);
    setState(() {
      _threads = data['threads'] as List;
      _posts = data['posts'] as List;
      _users = data['users'] as List;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    readJson();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            for (var thread in _threads)
              Column(
                children: [
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  Text(
                    thread["title"].toString(),
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 24,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  for (var post in _posts)
                    if (post["threadId"] == thread["id"])
                      Column(
                        children: [
                          for (var user in _users)
                            if (post["userId"] == user["id"])
                              Column(
                                children: [
                                  const SizedBox(height: 15),
                                  Text(user["name"].toString()),
                                  const SizedBox(height: 15),
                                ],
                              ),
                          Text(post["text"].toString()),
                        ],
                      )
                ],
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of this

```
for (var user in _users)
     if (post["userId"] == user["id"])
         Column(
           children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 15),
             Text(user["name"].toString()),
             const SizedBox(height: 15),
             ],
         ),
```

you can use listView builder this way :

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: _users.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
       return post["userId"] == _users[index]["id"]?
              Column(
                 children: [
                    const SizedBox(height: 15),
                    Text(_users[index]["name"].toString()),
                    const SizedBox(height: 15),
                 ],
              ):Container(); // in case post["userId"] != _users[index]["id"] you should return something for the list builder
       }])
```

also you would better change your Json file format to something like this to avoid the `if` clause :

```
threads: [
    {
      id: 't1',
      title: 'What is your favorite dog breed ?',
      publishedAt: 19191919191,
      userId: ''
      posts:[
        {
          id: 'p1',
          publishedAt: 19191919191,
          userId: 'u1',
          text: 'Golden Retriever',
          threadId: 't1'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```